# String converted when I send it in a structure with RF24 library

Tags: struct, arduino

I'm sending a data struct with the RF24 library from one node to another. This structure contains two string and one float.

When I send the structure with the transmitter and I print it to the serial output I get this:

```
El sensor PIR situat en Menjador te el valor 1.00
```

I see this in the receiver when I print it to the serial output:

```
El sensor œ>U situat en Üß§Å‹>r te el valor 1.00
```

Why are the two String changed ("PIR" and "Menjador")?

The structure is this:

```
struct sensorData {
  String  sensorType;
  String  sensorLocation;
  float   sensorValue;
} PIR1, sensor;
```

This is how I write it to the radio:

```
radio.write( &PIR1, sizeof(PIR1) ));
```

This is how I read it from the radio:

```
radio.read( &sensor, sizeof(sensor));
```

And this is how I print it to the serial output in the receiver:

```
  void printOutData(sensorData* data) {    
    Serial.print("El sensor ");
    Serial.print(data->sensorType);
    Serial.print(" situat en ");
    Serial.print(data->sensorLocation);
    Serial.print(" te el valor ");
    Serial.println(data->sensorValue);
  }
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String` type does not actually contain the bytes of the sensor type and location; it *points* to the bytes.  You are bascially sending the *memory address* of those bytes, not the bytes themselves.

You need to change your data structure so that it can *contain* the bytes inside the structure, with "C strings" aka "char arrays":

```
static const uint8_t SENSOR_TYPE_SIZE = 4;
static const uint8_t SENSOR_LOC_SIZE  = 12;

struct sensorData {
  char    sensorType[ SENSOR_TYPE_SIZE ];
  char    sensorLocation[ SENSOR_LOC_SIZE ];
  float   sensorValue;
} PIR1, sensor;
```

Of course, you will have to change how you set those member values.  Without your complete sketch, I can only offer a few possibilities:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  // Set to a constant value (i.e., a double-quoted string literal)

  strncpy( PIR1.sensorType, "TMP", sizeof(PIR.sensorType)-1 );
  PIR1.sensorType[ sizeof(PIR.sensorType)-1 ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate

  // Set to characters received over Serial, up to size-1 chars *or* a newline
  //   (This blocks until the line is entered!  Nothing else will happen
  //    until the line has been completely received.)

  size_t count = Serial.readBytesUntil( '\n', PIR1.sensorType, sizeof(PIR.sensorType)-1 );
  PIR.sensorType[ count ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate
}

void loop()
{
  // Non-blocking receive of a line.  Other things can be performed
  //    while we're waiting for the newline to arrive.

  if (Serial.available()) {

    //  A char finally came in!
    char c = Serial.read();

    // end-of-line?
    if (c == '\n') {

      // Pressed ENTER, send what we have now
      PIR.sensorLocation[ count ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate the C string
      radio.write( &PIR1, sizeof(PIR1) ));

      //  Reset for next time
      count = 0;

    } else { // not end-of-line, save another char (if there's room)

      if (count < sizeof(PIR.sensorLocation)-1) {
        PIR.sensorLocation[ count++ ] = c;
      }
    }
  }

  // Do some other things here... maybe check some buttons?
}
```

There are many reasons to avoid `String`, so switching to `char` arrays will actually pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know how the String works in this cases.
Maybe is less difficult to understand the code if I use an enum to define the values in this two variables...

Comment: Yes, the enums could be sent as a single byte, not multiple bytes for a char "name" of the type/location.  You also don't have to interpret the names in the receiver -- the enum values are ready to go.